# Maven: variable interpolation in POM

Tags: maven

In POM we can have `${project.version}`  or special variables like `${project.basedir}`.

This example at the very end of [Introduction to the POM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) accesses `project.properties.mavenVersion` by just writing `${mavenVersion}`.
 Why is that sufficient? I thought we need `${project.properties.mavenVersion}`.

In general, **when are we allowed to access a variable without fully qualifying it using`${project.xxx.variableName}`?**

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <mavenVersion>2.1</mavenVersion>        <----- variable defined here
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>    <----- variable accessed here
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>    <----- and here
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`project.` is the recommended form to use for all project variables except user defined (`<properties>` section) ones.

Comment: Thanks @Bax. Yes I understood that part. My confusion is, why can we just write `${mavenVersion}` instead of `${project.properties.mavenVersion}` (which is the standard way to resolve a variable)? Wouldn't there be a collision if `<mavenVersion>` appears somewhere else in the POM?